# Adding NOINDEX tag to products

Tags: product, magento-1, seo

We no longer have a web developer but need to add NOINDEX tags to all our products to help with our SEO

We have about 450 products at any one time

We are using Magento 1.8.1.0

We are complete novices when it comes to anything but the very basic Admin actions and all the answers we have seen instruct us to alter or add code.

This goes way above our heads.

Could someone please let us have step by step instructions on how to do this that even a complete novice can understand and implement

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1.) If you want to set `NOINDEX` for every page (product, CMS, ...), you can do this from backend: `Admin - System - Configuration - General - Design - HTML Head - Default Robots`.

2.) If you want to set it for all product pages, add this to your `app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/layout/local.xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

*(For other pages then "Catalog Product View" take a look at the other XML-files in layout folder to find the correct so called "Layout Handles" like `catalog_product_view`)*

3.) If you want to set it for a particular product, you can add this in product edit page `Tab: Design - Custom Layout Updates`

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I try and access the frontend I get this error message       You don't have permission to access /app/design/frontend/layout/local.xml on this server.    What do I do now?

Comment: @Dora there is no theme and package directory on your path?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/layout/local.xml` and add this:

```
<catalog_category_default> //category page 
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered> //category page with filters
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_product_view> //product view page
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

[Reference](http://doejo.com/blog/magento-how-to-add-noindex-nofollow-robots-meta-tag-or-change-meta-title-or-description-on-certain-pages/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm trying to implement this but keep getting   You don't have permission to access /app/design/frontend/layout/local.xml on this server.   What am I doing wrong

Comment: First, you should have this path `/app/design/frontend/YOUR PACKAGE/YOUR THEME/layout/local.xml` and check in layout folder if you have the 755 premission, local.xml 644

Comment: Hi Prince, Thanks for getting back to me so quickly, I'm obviously doing something completely wrong as I go to my admin section then don't know how to add the path you suggest, I am a complete beginner and really need a step by step instructions

Comment: ok, how did you to add the code to local.xml ?

Comment: I logged into my admin section, then went into the search box at the top of my safari screen and amended the URL by deleting everything back to index.php and added /app/design etc. I am sure this is wrong but don't know where else to add the path. I would have thought I needed to enter the path somewhere in the admin section but can't find anywhere to put it. we are using version 1.8

Comment: No, it's not like this, remove what you have added, now open the FTP(Filezilla) then connect you to your magento, after that go to `app/design/frontend/{your package name}/{your theme name}/layout/local.xml` and now put the code from my answer in this file `local.xml` at the bottom just before this tag `</layout>` then Save

Comment: Thanks thats just what I needed, I will try this later this afternoon and let you know the result